# Memory reservation using BCDEdit removememory/truncate

Tags: memory, memory-management, desktop-application, ram, software-design

We are trying to reserve memory in the RAM of windows PC by using the following command "BCDedit /set removememory 1024" which is reserving the last 1GB of RAM memory in PC. This will show the PC at boot entry that the RAM is 1GB less that what it actually is.
Ultimately, after reserving this 1GB of memory, we take the base address of this reserved memory from the Registry Entry under Hardware RESOURCEMAP\System Resources\Physical Memory We use the last address shown in the physical memory and use it as the base for the reserved memory. This address is given to an external Hardware device which uses this base address to write to the PC (through PCIe DMA transactions).

This working in some PCs where the base address taken from registry was correct and HW was able to write in the reserved 1GB memory. However, this process did not work (we got a blue screen crash) in some Windows PC and the following questions came up:

How can we guarantee that the reserved memory is not used by other devices (the last 1GB not accessible)?

What is the proper way to locate the address of the reserved memory, is there a different way than the Registry Entry?

Is there an optimization or protection done by PC that sets the memory to not be used by an external device even after using the BCDedit command which can cause the crash we are facing when HW initiates a write transaction to PC reserved memory?

Can we remove the optimization or protection done by windows to allow all PCs to work in the same manner meaning to allow the external HW to access the reserved 1GB memory?

We want to know the answers for the above questions and have a solution that allows the reserved memory to be used by the hardware in different PCs. If there are other methods recommended (workarounds) that can be done to allocate memory in PC (reserved) we are willing to try it.

What about the possibility of adding a external RAM memory (via USB for example), and using that memory for our hardware. Would the address always be the same, is this recommended to be done, is this a possible solution? Assuming this RAM is not visible by windows and only used for our process.

This working in some PCs where the base address taken from registry was correct and HW was able to write in the reserved 1GB memory.

We want to know the answers for the above questions and have a solution that allows the reserved memory to be used by the hardware in different PCs. If there are other methods recommended (workarounds) that can be done to allocate memory in PC (reserved) we are willing to try it.